Package pgf Error: No shape named * is known in LaTeX with TikZ for Neural Network Plot
I'm working on visualizing a neural network architecture using LaTeX with TikZ, specifically using the PlotNeuralNet library. I am encountering an error related to node referencing.
The latex code is generated from https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet
Python Code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
sys.path.append('../')  # Adjust the path if needed
from pycore.tikzeng import *

def to_FullyConnected( name, s_filer=" ", n_filer=" ", offset="(0,0,0)", to="(0,0,0)", width=1.5, height=3, depth=25, opacity=0.8, caption=" " , zlabelposition='midway'):
    return r"""
\pic[shift={"""+ offset +"""}] at """+ to +"""
    {Box={
        name=""" + name +""",
        caption=""" +caption + """,
        xlabel={{ """+ '"'+str(n_filer) +'", "dummy"'+ """ }},
        zlabel="""+ str(s_filer) +""",
        zlabelposition="""+zlabelposition+""",
        fill=\FcColor,
        bandfill=\FcReluColor,
        opacity="""+ str(opacity) +""",
        height="""+ str(height) +""",
        width="""+ str(width) +""",
        depth="""+ str(depth) +"""
        }
    };
"""

# Architecture of the SiameseModelWithSwin
arch = [
    to_head('..'),
    to_cor(),
    to_begin(),

    # Input images (placeholders)
    to_input('../cropped_HnE_1.png', name="input_fixed_image"),  # Update with the path to your input images
    to_input('../Xenium.png', name="input_moving_image"),  # Update with the path to your input images

    # Swin Encoder
    to_Conv("swin_encoder", s_filer=256, n_filer=64, offset="(2,0,0)", to="(0,0,0)", width=2, height=40, depth=40, caption="Swin Encoder"),
    to_connection("input_fixed_image", "swin_encoder"),

    # Fully connected layers
    to_FullyConnected("fc1", s_filer=128, n_filer=512, offset="(3,0,0)", to="(swin_encoder-east)", width=2, height=4, depth=40, caption="FC1"),
    to_connection("swin_encoder", "fc1"),

    to_FullyConnected("fc2", s_filer=64, n_filer=256, offset="(4,0,0)", to="(fc1-east)", width=2, height=4, depth=20, caption="FC2"),
    to_connection("fc1", "fc2"),

    to_FullyConnected("fc3", s_filer=32, n_filer=6, offset="(5,0,0)", to="(fc2-east)", width=2, height=4, depth=10, caption="FC3"),
    to_connection("fc2", "fc3"),

    # Output
    to_SoftMax("output", 6, offset="(5,0,0)", to="(fc3-east)", width=1, height=2, depth=5, caption="Output"),
    to_connection("fc3", "output"),

    to_end()
]

def main():
    namefile = str(sys.argv[0]).split('.')[0]
    to_generate(arch, namefile + '.tex')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

plot_siamese_model.tex
\documentclass[border=8pt, multi, tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{import}
\subimport{../layers/}{init}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{3d} %for including external image 

\def\ConvColor{rgb:yellow,5;red,2.5;white,5}
\def\ConvReluColor{rgb:yellow,5;red,5;white,5}
\def\PoolColor{rgb:red,1;black,0.3}
\def\UnpoolColor{rgb:blue,2;green,1;black,0.3}
\def\FcColor{rgb:blue,5;red,2.5;white,5}
\def\FcReluColor{rgb:blue,5;red,5;white,4}
\def\SoftmaxColor{rgb:magenta,5;black,7}   
\def\SumColor{rgb:blue,5;green,15}

\newcommand{\copymidarrow}{\tikz \draw[-Stealth,line width=0.8mm,draw={rgb:blue,4;red,1;green,1;black,3}] (-0.3,0) -- ++(0.3,0);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{connection}=[ultra thick,every node/.style={sloped,allow upside down},draw=\edgecolor,opacity=0.7]
\tikzstyle{copyconnection}=[ultra thick,every node/.style={sloped,allow upside down},draw={rgb:blue,4;red,1;green,1;black,3},opacity=0.7]

\node[canvas is zy plane at x=0] (input_fixed_image) at (-3,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{../cropped_HnE_1.png}};

\node[canvas is zy plane at x=0] (input_moving_image) at (-3,0,0) {\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{../Xenium.png}};

\pic[shift={(2,0,0)}] at (0,0,0) 
    {Box={
        name=swin_encoder,
        caption=Swin Encoder,
        xlabel={{64, }},
        zlabel=256,
        fill=\ConvColor,
        height=40,
        width=2,
        depth=40
        }
    };

\draw [connection]  (input_fixed_image-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (swin_encoder-west);

\pic[shift={(3,0,0)}] at (swin_encoder-east) 
    {Box={
        name=fc1,
        caption=FC1,
        xlabel={{ "512", "dummy" }},
        zlabel=128,
        zlabelposition=midway,
        fill=\FcColor,
        bandfill=\FcReluColor,
        opacity=0.8,
        height=4,
        width=2,
        depth=40
        }
    };

\draw [connection]  (swin_encoder-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (fc1-west);

\pic[shift={(4,0,0)}] at (fc1-east) 
    {Box={
        name=fc2,
        caption=FC2,
        xlabel={{ "256", "dummy" }},
        zlabel=64,
        zlabelposition=midway,
        fill=\FcColor,
        bandfill=\FcReluColor,
        opacity=0.8,
        height=4,
        width=2,
        depth=20
        }
    };

\draw [connection]  (fc1-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (fc2-west);

\pic[shift={(5,0,0)}] at (fc2-east) 
    {Box={
        name=fc3,
        caption=FC3,
        xlabel={{ "6", "dummy" }},
        zlabel=32,
        zlabelposition=midway,
        fill=\FcColor,
        bandfill=\FcReluColor,
        opacity=0.8,
        height=4,
        width=2,
        depth=10
        }
    };

\draw [connection]  (fc2-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (fc3-west);

\pic[shift={(5,0,0)}] at (fc3-east) 
    {Box={
        name=output,
        caption=Output,
        xlabel={{" ","dummy"}},
        zlabel=6,
        fill=\SoftmaxColor,
        opacity=0.8,
        height=2,
        width=1,
        depth=5
        }
    };

\draw [connection]  (fc3-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (output-west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Run:
python plot_siamese_model.py   
pdflatex plot_siamese_model.tex

Traceback:
Package pgf Error: No shape named input_fixed_image-east is known.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please ask only one question here. And can you please show us the resulting TeX code resulting in your issue?

The latex code is from:
https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet

Can you show plot_siamese_model.tex?

Ok added plot_siamese_model.tex. Thank you for your patience. It's my first time using latex.

Does the file really end in the middle of the tikzpicture?

Question amended

try input_fixed_image.east instead of input_fixed_image-east and similarly for other node references. if the errors are produced by the python code, amend the python code instead. as far as I can see, which isn't far it being python, the script is responsible for inserting the hyphens rather than dots and should be corrected.

This question is stranded with no answer and no indication from OP if fixing the python code as suggested by @cfr in the comments worked:

try input_fixed_image.east instead of input_fixed_image-east and
similarly for other node references. if the errors are produced by the
python code, amend the python code instead. as far as I can see, which
isn't far it being python, the script is responsible for inserting the
hyphens rather than dots and should be corrected.

Some people are against closing questions - as they can help others in the future -So I am reposting the comment as a possible answer
